# Question on Rudin's Proof of the Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

The Theorem in question is Theorem 10.42.: If $f$ is meromorphic in $U$, $A$ is the set of poles of $f$ and $\Gamma$ is a cycle in $U-A$ so that $Ind _{\Gamma}=0$ in $U^c$ then
\begin{equation}\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}f=\sum_{a\in A}Ind_{\Gamma}(a)Res_f(a)
\end{equation}
My problem is with the first part of the proof, i.e. proving that the sum, or equivalently the set $B=\left\{a\in A:Ind_{\Gamma}(a)\neq 0\right\}$ is finite. The proof goes like this:

Every component $V$ of $(\Gamma^*)^c$ (that is a component of the interior, or the exterior of $\Gamma$) that is unbounded or intersects $U^c$ is in the exterior of $\Gamma$ ($Ind_{\Gamma}=0$ in $V$). Since $A$ has no limit points in $U$, ***we conclude that*** $B$ is a finite set.

How exactly do we conclude that? The arguments made before that are pretty obvious but this one is not. I am thinking that $B$ is bounded and with no limit points, but that does not make it finite right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any set $B$ which is bounded and has no limit points must be finite.

Otherwise you can find a sequence $x_n \in B$ with $x_n \neq x_m, \forall m \neq n$.

Since $B$ is bounded, its closure is bounded and closed, thus compact. Hence $x_n$ has a subsequence which is convergent in $\bar{B}$. But then, the limit is a limit point for $B$.

Comment: I suppose that only works for subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ (due to Heine Borel Theorem) and not of general metric spaces?

Comment: @Optional If you are in a general metric space I think you need the extra assumption that $U$ is a subset of a compact set.

Comment: @Optional Yes. For a counter example in the general case, take the discrete metric on an infinite set.

Comment: I have a question on above answer. The assumption is not limit points in $U$. What the answer given is there exists a limit point in $\bar B$. Is it possible that $\bar B \not\subset U$? In this case, the limit point may be not in $U$. There is no contradiction.

Comment: @user3585161 Note that $Ind_{\Gamma}(x)$ is locally constant and  $Ind_{\Gamma}(x)=0$ outside $U$.